# Best way of showing over 200 annotation pins iOS9 swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, annotations, mkmapview

I have a mapView in my app that should show over 200 annotation pins. So far I have just under 100 pins added and it got me wondering. Isn't there a smarter way of showing them? The code is really long at the moment, and I fear it being even longer. Below you can see how I added the pins (with an example of just one pin). How can I do this in a smarter way?

```
let first = Artwork(title: "First annotation",
                              locationName: "Tryk for rute",
                              discipline: "Butik",
                              coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.931326, longitude: 12.284186))

map.addAnnotation(first)
```

Those to pieces of code is written for around 100 annotation pins - there must be a better way!

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: What does your data array look like? If you can post it, we'll be able to answer with proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here that the data for your annotations are not stored in objects in an array, and that you've got 100 copies of your example code.

If the information is static, you could include the information in a property list (plist).

Your plist may look something like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>Locations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>First annotation</string>
            ... more information here
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Second annotation</string>
            ... more information here
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You can then load the plist and iterate the locations array to add your annotations to the map. Something like this:

```
func addAnnotations()
    {
        // load your plist
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("StaticInformation", ofType: "plist") {
            if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                // get your static locations information as an array
                if let locations = dict["Locations"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
                    // iterate your locations
                    for (index, location) in locations.enumerate() {

                        let title = location["Title"] as? String
                        // obtain the information needed from the location dict

                        // create your annotation
                        let first = Artwork(title: title,
                                            locationName: ...,
                                            discipline: ...,
                                            coordinate: ...)

                        map.addAnnotation(first)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is not tested, sorry. But hopefully you get the idea.